# Ktor - Unit testing is throwing 404

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, junit, httprequest, ktor

I have a simple program in Ktor. It runs perfectly, but when I run the unit testing class it only throws this error: "expected:<200 OK> but was:<404 Not Found>"

This is my unit test code:

```
class ApplicationTest {
@Test
fun testRoot() = testApplication {
    val response = client.get("/")
    assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.status)
}

@Test
fun testStart() = testApplication {
    val response = client.post("/start")
    assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.status)
}
}
```

This is my Application.kt:

```
const val enableHTTPS = false
const val portHTTP = 80
const val portHTTPS = 7001


lateinit var environment: ApplicationEngineEnvironment
fun main() {
    initEnvironment()

    embeddedServer(Netty, environment = environment).start(wait = true)
}
```

My routing file is:

```
fun Application.configureRouting() {
    routing {
        get {
            call.respond(ApiDetails())
        }

        post("/start") {
            call.response.status(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        }

        post("/move") {
            val gameDetails: GameDetails = call.receive()
            val move = BasicStrategy().move(gameDetails, application)

            call.respond(move)
        }

        post("/end") {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To test an application, its [modules](https://ktor.io/docs/modules.html) should be loaded to `testApplication`. Loading modules to `testApplication` depends on the way used to [create a server](https://ktor.io/docs/create-server.html): by using the `application.conf` configuration file or in code using the `embeddedServer` function.

If you have the `application.conf` file in the resources folder, `testApplication` loads all modules and properties specified in the configuration file automatically.

You can disable loading modules by customizing an [environment](https://ktor.io/docs/testing.html#environment) for tests.

If you use `embeddedServer`, you can add modules to a test application manually using the application function:

```
fun testModule1() = testApplication {
    application {
        module1()
        module2()
    }
}
```

In your case:

```
class ApplicationTest {
@Test
fun testRoot() = testApplication {
    application {
        configureRouting()
    }
    environment {
        config = MapApplicationConfig(
            "ktor.deployment.port" to "80",
            "ktor.deployment.sslPort" to "7001"
        )
    }
    val response = client.get("/")
    assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.status)
}

@Test
fun testStart() = testApplication {
    application {
        configureRouting()
    }
    environment {
        config = MapApplicationConfig(
            "ktor.deployment.port" to "80",
            "ktor.deployment.sslPort" to "7001"
        )
    }
    val response = client.post("/start")
    assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.status)
}
```

}